# Why the download button do not work?

Tags: html

How I create download button using html!

The code is like:

```
<a herf="so.jpg" download>a herf="so.jpg" download</a>
{<a href="so.jpg" download>download</a>}
```

But it does not work.

What can I do for this?

I do not know how to write the correct code for solving this problem.

Please help me.

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

There are no "Download-Buttons", you can either create a a-tag and let it look like a button with css

```
<a href="your-download-link-to-the-file" download>File to download</a>
```

or you write 1-2 lines javascript and when Download File is clicked you start the download of file xy..

Answer (score 0):

Put a download tag to force download file.

```
<a href="so.jpg" download> Download </a>
```